# How to display the values returned by count in SQL

Tags: mysql

i keep having this error **"mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in"** when i try to display the returned value of count in sql. heres my code.

```
$query="SELECT med_rec_ID, COUNT(med_rec_ID) 
        FROM med_issue 
        WHERE MONTH(issue_date) = MONTH('2013-02-05')
        GROUP BY med_rec_ID";
$result= mysql_query($query);
while($count = mysql_fetch_array($display3)){
    echo $count[0];
}
```

i have tried to run the query in sql alone it displays 2 columns (the med_rec_ID, and the COUNT). guys how do i display the count and fix the error too?

Comment: may be you are getting error because resource is saved in $result and you are giving $display3 in mysql_fetch_array. May be you should give mysql_fetch_array($result).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `mysql_*` functions since they're deprecated.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Secondly, look at what you're passing into the `fetch_array` function.

You probably want to do something like:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "pass", "db_name");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
$medIds[] = $row['med_rec_ID'];
... 
}
```

Then fix the count by giving it an alias.

Please note that you should actually store how you access the DB in a more secure manner, but I use this only to illustrate the example.  Here's a pretty good post: [How to create global configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971365/how-to-create-global-configuration-file)

Answer (score 0):

Give it an alias:

```
SELECT 
  med_rec_ID, 
  COUNT(med_rec_ID) TheCount
FROM med_issue 
where MONTH(issue_date) =     MONTH('2013-02-05') GROUP BY med_rec_ID
```

then you can select that column `TheCount` inside the while loop with `$row['TheCount']`, also use lope through the `$result`:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['TheCount'];
}
```

Comment: i still keep getting that error. i dont know what im doing wrong with the query, it is ok when i run it in sql alone.

Comment: @Cadz Run this query directly to MySQL, and post the error you got.

Comment: i have run the query in mysql i told you. it doesnt give any errors.

Comment: @Cadz - See my edit. The problem might be because of the `mysql_fetch_array($display3)` use `$result` instead of `$display3` like in my edit.

Comment: lol whats the difference in using $display3 and $result. and ive tried it it still doesnt work

Comment: @Cadz - What is that variable `$display3` in your code? The result set coming from your query will be in the `$result` since you do this: `$result = mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

Is your query even executing? that error will happen if mysql_query doesnt return the resource, in case query fails

```
$query="SELECT med_rec_ID, COUNT(med_rec_ID) as C FROM med_issue where MONTH(issue_date) =     MONTH('2013-02-05') GROUP BY med_rec_ID";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    echo $row["C"];
   }
```

Note: Please do not use mysql_* functions anymore

Comment: i belive its not executing properly and i dont know why. but when i run the query alone in sql page. it displays properly what i wanted to display.

Comment: running that code should display an error which will help figuring it out