# Notice: Undefined variable: config in C:\xampp\htdocs\global.php on line 13

Tags: php, content-management-system

my first question:-) exiting.....

i'm buizy with a new CMS and i'm getting this error.....

```
Notice: Undefined variable: config in C:\xampp\htdocs\global.php on line 13
```

I checked my code twice, but it seems like nothing is wrong to me? if someone of you sees it please answer the question...

Here is my global.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Config
require_once "inc/config.php";

// Classes

require_once "inc/classes/class.tpl.php";

// Database connectie via MySQLi

$db = new mysqli($config["database"]["host"], $config["database"]["user"], $config["database"]["pass"], $config["database"]["name"]);

if($db->connect_error){
    die("Pik, zet je database eens goed?");
}

?>
```

Thanx for your time...

*EDIT:

My config.php

```
<?php
$_CONFIG['database']['host'] = 'localhost';
$_CONFIG['database']['username'] = 'root';
$_CONFIG['database']['pass'] = 'assembla1';
$_CONFIG['database']['database'] = 'data';
?>
```

Comment: What does the code look like in inc/config.php?

Comment: It would appear that if your `config.php` page is either not generating the $config variable array, or the $config array is not being returned to the global scope. This would mean that there is no variable $config['database']['host'] etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be with your `global.php`, but could also have to do with the two files you are using under `require_once`. Makes sure the array `$config` is defined/created in one of them. If it isn't, then you know why the error arises.

Now that we know you have `$_CONFIG` defined in your `config.php` file, you should probably try to access the variable in the right manner - using it through a `constructor` instead. Look at [How to create global configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971365/how-to-create-global-configuration-file) and `mario's` answer for more detail:

P.S. I am not able to comment on the question. Hence, threw in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
$config["database"]["user"]
```

and in your config it is

```
$_CONFIG['database']['username'] = 'root';
```